# forEach mongodb PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, csv, foreach

Is there an efficient way to use forEach in mongodb with PHP, The problem is to be able to add a new row to CSV file for every element in the result array. The one of the possible solution was to use

$data is the mongo cursor

```
    $records = iterator_to_array($data);
    $file = fopen("contacts.csv","w");
    foreach ($records as $record){            
        fputcsv($file,$record);
    }
```

But, loading the entire data into memory is not a scalable option to my problem, as the data can be huge.Is there a better alternative by some way be able to use forEach. How to use forEach with mongo PHP

Comment: If `$data` is an object that implements the `Iterator` interface, you can use `foreach` on `$data` directly. There's no need to convert it to a simple array. http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php

Comment: Need to use the forEach within the mongo db

Comment: I understand `$data` is the mongodb cursor. You can simply `foreach ($data as $record)` to iterate over it. It doesn't need to be an array at that stage, but you can call `iterator_to_array($record)` inside the loop to use with `fputcsv()` and avoid loading it all into memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$file = fopen("contacts.csv","w");
foreach ($data as $record){            
    $contact = iterator_to_array($record);    
    fputcsv($file,$contact);
}
```

This solution works as the $data remains cursor and iterator_to_array() inside loop converts individual record into array to be placed in CSV file.